# Set maxDate and minDate for datepicker in javascript, not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, datepicker

I have checked lot of tutorials and QAs in Google and tried with all permutation and combination tricks. Still my calender is not restricted with `maxDate` and `minDate` as I set. Please can someone check and let me know whats wrong with my code.

my javascript function is

```
$(function () {

    $("[id$=txtPaymentDate]").datepicker({
        maxDate: "+0D",
        showOn: 'button',
        dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
        buttonImageOnly: true
    });
});
```

...and my `body` code:

```html
<td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPaymentDate" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="(YYYY-MM-DD)"></asp:TextBox>
    <span id="spnAltContactNumber" style="color: Red;" runat="server"></span>
</td>
```

***EDIT***

Even though I've set `dateFormat as 'yyyy-mm-dd'`, it is still showing the date as `mm/dd/yyyy`.

I have these following scripts. Is there any extra is required?

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Which `datepicker` plugin you are using?

Comment: @ Rao what that mean?i really have no idea on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this maxDate and minDate does not work.Instead u need to use **startDate** and **endDate** as below.

```
$("[id$=txtPaymentDate]").datepicker({
                showOn: 'button',
                dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                startDate: '-5d',//previous date
                endDate: new Date()//current date

            });
```

Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

change textbox accoring to .net

```js
 $( function() {
    $( "#txtPaymentDate" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd M yy',maxDate: 1});
  } );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<td>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="txtPaymentDate"></p>
 </td>
```

it should be maxDate: 1
$( "#datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd M yy',maxDate: 1});

Comment: Here whwn i run code snippet its working cool.But when i integrated in my code exactly,its still its not freezing maxdate:_(((

Comment: can you show me the link... or have you checked is there another id with same name ?

Comment: last two <script> are showing with underline.Is that mean i have to download them?

Comment: nope those are online script, you can download if you want

Comment: so what to do now to make my calendar work?i have tried all.What might be reason ?

Comment: can you use simple textbox instead of .net   <input type="text" id="txtPaymentDate">

Comment: Yaeh i tried this already.But it dint worked.Accepted answer did.logic is simple.Thank you nishant